# Ubuntu does not start after a skipped Mok management blue screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, secure-boot

The system update was running.

Suddenly, a dialog box appeared to ask me for a password that I had to type twice.

After that, System Update stated that a reboot was requered in order to complete some updates.

I rebooted.

A blue box appeared in which I could read the Word "Mok", but, as I did not know what It was, I passed away without entering in what appeared to be some kind of configuration.

After that, Ubuntu freezes on booting.

I can boot into Windows, but not into Ubuntu, even if I select any previous Kernel.

On startup, I entered the UEFI (or BIOS) configuration of my laptop and disabled secure boot. Aftewards, I can use Ubuntu with no problems, but want to enable secure boot (I have another patition with windows).

I can boot live version from USB (I do not have a CD-ROM unit) and use it with no problem.

From the live Ubuntu, I can access the Ubuntu partition. I looked for too files:

- /var/log/boot.log  This file exists, but its date and time of creation (Jul 20 16:37 boot.log) is that of my last successful boot (and contains no errors), before the problem started, so it seems that now, the boot.log is not even created.
- /var/log/dmesg   This file does not exist.

Also, the most recent file in /var/log/ was last modified before the problem took place.

When I boot from the hard drive (secure boot disabled), I can get the following from a terminal:

```
$ mokutil --list-enrolled
MokListRT is empty
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic     4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1  amd64  Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.18.0-18-generic     4.18.0-18.19~18.04.1  amd64  Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic     4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1  amd64  Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04     4.18.0.25.74          amd64  Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-virtual-hwe-18.04     4.18.0.25.74          amd64  Virtual Linux kernel image
$ uname -a
Linux VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X430FN-S430FN 4.18.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 27 07:28:31 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So I interpret (anybody who knows about secure boot can correct me) that the linux kernel is signed, but the sign is not in the Mok database. How could I complete the signing process?.

Could an Ubuntu reinstall solve the problem?. If so, how could I check for any debris left by the non-complete Mok enrollment on the hard disk or even in the BIOS/UEFI?

Thanks in avance.